# How to make Selenium click on this button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to extract all articles on this web page, but i can't make Selenium click on the "Continue" button at the end of the page.
I have tried a lot of different versions, but i'll post just the one, which at least doesn't throw an error...:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

addr = 'https://www.armani.com/de/armanicom/giorgio-armani/f%C3%BCr-ihn/alle-kleidungsstucke'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(addr)

ContinueButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='nextPage']")
# gives: No error, but also no effect

# ContinueButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[8]/a/span[2]")
# gives: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[8]/a/span[2]"}

#ContinueButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nextPage > a:nth-child(1)")
# gives: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
 
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ContinueButton).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Chrome engine is v86, but i have tried (and failed) with Firefox as well.

Comment: Are you closing the newsletter dialog box which is coming on the first page load?

Comment: There is a CookiePolicy footer which might intercept your click. Try to `driver.find_element_by_id('footer_tc_privacy_button').click()` to close footer before clicking Next button

Comment: I have closed it manually (as i don't know yet how to do that in the program), but it didn't help.

Comment: Adding the footer click, gives the following error message: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="footer_tc_privacy_button"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)

Comment: Ok. Show error for just Next button click. Your initial problem

Comment: Just added some more versions i tried in the code as remarks. For the original Next button click no error is shown, but it doesn't have en effect either. As you can see i have tried other versions as well, but none work. Some observations that might be unrelated to the problem: i noticed, that only the first few article pictures are loaded, not all of them. Another thing is: sometimes the page loads, but does not show the row with the other article pages and the continue button at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to wait for the element to be clickable and then attempt to click on it:
I
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

```
addr = 'https://www.armani.com/de/armanicom/giorgio-armani/f%C3%BCr-ihn/alle-kleidungsstucke'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(addr)

ContinueButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='nextPage']/a")))

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ContinueButton).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Ok, now this looks promising. When i add this to your code 
'driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", ContinueButton)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ContinueButton).perform()
time.sleep(3)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ContinueButton).click()
time.sleep(5)'
i can see how the element is found & hovered over - but the click doesn't cause an action.
Two observations: 1. i need to place the mouse pointer in the browser, otherwise the element is not found. 2. If there are popups (newsletter,cookie footer), i need to close them manually, otherwise i get an error.

Comment: Another update: using your code and 'driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ContinueButton)' instead of 'ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ContinueButton).click()' the click is executed!
However, now i run into a new problem as the website responds "You don't have permission to access http://..." Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you are clicking on the `li` element.

Your click is received but no action is performed, in order to do so you need to target the `a` element after the `li`.

Try this:

`ContinueButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='nextPage']/a")`

Comment: Results in the same error: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='nextPage']/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)

Comment: I have tested the code locally and find no such error. One change that I have made is removing the ActionChains with ```ContinueButton.click()```

Comment: No change. The basic problem seems to be that the button cannot be located.

Comment: I am able to run the code perfectly on my local computer. There are just 3 changes which I made to your code, I added the path to my chrome driver ```driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe')```, added ```/a``` to the XPATH, and replaced ActionChains with a simple ```.click()```

Comment: No, doesn't work either. It seems to be a general problem as i just tried the same script on other web pages, getting the same error.

Comment: The website uses bot protection and has blocked my IP. I am getting an ```Access Denied``` error. Are you using selenium on headless mode? Try to visually if the webpage opened is correct before making the click.

Comment: I've tried non-headless so far. The site shows not entirely correct: as i described earlier, it shows only the first few article pictures, the others are just blank. Sometimes (if the cookies footer shows up i think) the whole row with other links to other pages and the continue button is missing, too.

Comment: Try to locate the button in Chrome Dev Tools, if you can not find it there then the code will not work.

Comment: Well, i used the dev tools to locate the button initially.

Comment: The access denied error might be the result of too many requests to the site, which i experienced, too. However, that is not my core problem. With y code, the element is not found, and if it is (for the li element it works), neither click(), nor click().perform() will cause any action, unfortunately.

Comment: It is quite unfortunate to know that you are facing this problem. Kindly update here if you find a solution so that others may benefit in the future as well. I can also share a video demonstration showing the working of the above mentioned code as well.